# logicals of shared rows of two data frames

Tags: r

How do I get the logicals of shared rows of two data frames?

```
> a <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 7:11)
> b <- data.frame(x = c(4, 2, 6, 3, 3, 1), y = c(10, 16, 7, 9, 9, 7))
> a
  x  y
1 1  7
2 2  8
3 3  9
4 4 10
5 5 11
> b
  x  y
1 4 10
2 2 16
3 6  7
4 3  9
5 3  9
6 1  7
> a.indices <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
> b.indices <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

I would like to return a.indices or b.indices.

Comment: Depending what your next step is, you may want to try `merge(b, a)`. That does much the same thing as `b[b.indices, ]`.

Comment: @bdemarest - `merge` does seems to suggest itself here - I've added an answer to the exact question incorporating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a combinaton of what `merge` and `%in%` does

```
a.indices <- match(
  do.call(paste, c(a, sep="\r")), 
  do.call(paste, c(b, sep="\r")), nomatch=0
)>0
```

You combine the rows into a single value and then use match to compare one set to the other. You could also do

```
b.indices <- Reduce(function(vprev,vnow) vprev & !is.na(vnow), 
    Map(match, b,a), init=T)
```

(for both these methods you can swap `a` and `b` to get the opposite result). You may wish to test to compare performance in your specific scenario.

Comment: Your first solution works for me, but I don't understand it. How do the functions do.call, paste and c all work together?
c(a, sep = "\r") creates a data frame with column names x, y and sep.
do.call applies paste to the three columns of the data frame.
What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `do.call` takes an function and a list and calls the function using values in the list as parameters. So essentially it's calling `paste(a$x, a$y, sep="\r")` but this way it will work for any number of columns. It turns all the columns into a single mega-column (vector) since `match` only works on atomic vectors. Also `c(a, sep="\r")` does not add a column to the data.frame `a`. It down casts `a` to a simple list then adds an additional element to that list. We never add a new column to `a` (or `b`).